# Python 2.7 Scapy: Can someone explain why only server side socket showing as ESTABLISHED and Client side connection is not showing as ESTABLISHED

Tags: python, sockets, scapy

Python Scapy: Can someone explain why only server-side socket is showing as ESTABLISHED and Client side connection is not showing as ESTABLISHED after 3-way handshake through Scapy tool?

I have used these below commands to craft SYN & ACK from my client.

```
ip=IP(src=192.168.40.20,dst=192.168.40.40)
SYN=TCP(sport=15678,dport=6789,flags='S',seq=1000)
SYNACK=sr1(ip/SYN)
ACK=TCP(sport=15678, dport=6789, flags='A', seq=SYNACK.ack, ack=SYNACK.seq +1) 
send(ip/ACK)
```

and used My program as a Server which listens on 192.168.40.40:6789

But, the ESTABLISHED socket is being shown only on the server side, but not on the Client side. Can someone make me understand how this happens?

Comment: Because you aren't using TCP at the client, you are implementing it yourself, so the client TCP doesn't know anything about the connection.

Comment: Thank you EJP for the reply. Now, I could understand why it's happening. But, for transferring(send/receive) data between server & client through TCP, the connection has to go to ESTABLISHED state on both the sides, right? How Scapy deals with this?